# How do I fix my PEM block in ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate

Using golang and gin for an SSL webserver. I made my csr and key files. But I get:

```
crypto/tls: failed to find "CERTIFICATE" PEM block in certificate input
after skipping PEM blocks of the following types: [CERTIFICATE REQUEST]
```

Any idea where to go from here? The line that reads the file is:

https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/develop/gin.go#L230

I made my files with:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out <private key file name>.key 2048

openssl req -new -key <private key file name>.key -out <csr file name>.csr
```

Comment: .csr 's format is PKCS10, and .crt's format is PEM. more: http://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file

Answer (score 6):

I was confusing .csr file vs a .crt file.

Comment: Command to extract certificates from csr:


`kubectl get csr myuser -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}'| base64 -d > myuser.crt`

Ref https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#get-the-certificate